# Sublime Text 2 : tried to make symlink to subl, but I did it in wrong directory

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

Sublime Text 2 : tried to make symlink to subl in Terminal, but I did it in wrong directory, simple_cms......and after I put like below in simple_cms file....the prompt changed like '>' ....
simple_cms

```
VeryBerryS2$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Did I do something wrong and How do I undo it?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I don't know how to undo this...

Answer (score 1):

You opened a `"` without closing it. The `>` prompt means that the command shell is still waiting for you to finish typing the rest of the command. Hit Ctrl+C and start over.